# Map Angular Array to Object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have been looking and have found a few good references for transforming arrays to objects, but I can't seem to find my use case. I have an array with the following format

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'hello', display: false},
  {id: 5, name: 'hello2', display: true},
  {id: 7, name: 'hello8', display: true},
]
```

and I would like to map it into something like this

```
{
  5: {id: 5, name: 'hello2'},
  7: {id: 7, name: 'hello8'}
}
```

I have been trying to use the map function, but I can't figure it out since I want the keys of my map to be an id. This is what I have so far but it is obviously wrong.

```
const myArray = [
  {id: 1, name: 'hello', display: false},
  {id: 5, name: 'hello2', display: true},
  {id: 7, name: 'hello8', display: true},
];

const myMap = myArray.filter(row => row.display)
                     .map(row => {
                         return {row.id: {id: row.id, name: row.name}
                     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the array, map it to pairs of `[id, obj]`, and convert to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`. You can use destructuring and rest syntax (`...`) to remove `display`.

Notes: if `Object.fromEntries()` is not supported, change `target` in TS Config to `ES2019`.

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, name: 'hello', display: false},{id: 5, name: 'hello2', display: true}, {id: 7, name: 'hello8', display: true}]

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  arr.filter(o => o.display)
    .map(({ display, ...o }) => [o.id, o])
)

console.log(result)
```

Another option is to use `Array.reduce()` to create the object. In that case, you can skip objects with false `display`.

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, name: 'hello', display: false},{id: 5, name: 'hello2', display: true}, {id: 7, name: 'hello8', display: true}]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, { display, ...o }) => {
  if(display) acc[o.id] = [o.id, o]

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I am getting an error about `fromEntries()` not being a function, but I am currently on `es2017`. I am upgrading to `es2019` and will get back if it works

Comment: If not, use the 2nd solution, which doesn't require changes to the `target`.

Comment: thank you. I feel like there should be an easier way to convert an array into an object but your solution works for me

Comment: Not in native js. In lodash, for example, you have `_.keyBy(arr, 'id')`, but it won't filter or remove `display`.